# How to create a pathlib relative path with a dot starting point?

Tags: python, django, environment-variables, pathlib

I needed to create a relative path starting with the current directory as a "." dot

For example, in windows ".\envs\.some.env" or "./envs/.some.env" elsewhere

I wanted to do this using pathlib. A solution was found, but it has a kludgy replace statement.  Is there a better way to do this using pathlib?

The usage was django-environ, and the goal was to support multiple env files. The working folder contained an envs folder with the multiple env files within that folder.

```
import environ
from pathlib import Path
import os

domain_env = Path.cwd()

dotdot = Path("../")
some_env = dotdot / "envs" / ".some.env"

envsome = environ.Env()
envsome.read_env(envsome.str(str(domain_env), str(some_env).replace("..", ".")))  

print(str(some_env))
print(str(some_env).replace("..", "."))

dot = Path("./")    # Path(".") gives the same result
some_env = dot / "envs" / ".some.env"

print(str(some_env))
```

On windows gives:

```
..\envs\.some.env
.\envs\.some.env
envs\.some.env
```

Comment: Why does `envs\.some.env` not suffice? For common uses like `Path('envs\\.some.env').open()` vs `Path('.\\envs\\.some.env').open()` they should be the same thing.

Comment: `.\\` is the current directory, it can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. Using the django-environ module, the only way I could make it work was with the dot present for the current directory.  Then I wanted to migrate to a pathlib solution.

Comment: Then just simply `os.path.join('.', str(some_env))` at the end.

Comment: Yes that would work, and there are places where the os library has more functionality than pathlib.  This may be one of those places. I'm wondering if there is a pathlib approach for this.

Comment: I had this *exact* question just now because I am creating a path I'm passing to a nodejs `require()` statement, where `./something.js` and `something.js` are interpreted differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a multi-platform idea:

```
import ntpath
import os
import posixpath
from pathlib import Path, PurePosixPath, PureWindowsPath


def dot_path(pth):
    """Return path str that may start with '.' if relative."""
    if pth.is_absolute():
        return os.fsdecode(pth)
    if isinstance(pth, PureWindowsPath):
        return ntpath.join(".", pth)
    elif isinstance(pth, PurePosixPath):
        return posixpath.join(".", pth)
    else:
        return os.path.join(".", pth)


print(dot_path(PurePosixPath("file.txt")))    # ./file.txt
print(dot_path(PureWindowsPath("file.txt")))  # .\file.txt
print(dot_path(Path("file.txt")))             # one of the above, depending on host OS
print(dot_path(Path("file.txt").resolve()))   # (e.g.) /path/to/file.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

The best I could find was (as suggested by [*metatoaster* in the question’s comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62687193/how-to-create-a-pathlib-relative-path-with-a-dot-starting-point#comment110857859_62687193)):

```py
os.path.join(".", some_env)
```

where `some_env` may either be a string or `bytes` or ([since Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)) any [path-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object) (which means you don’t have to convert your `Path` objects to strings anymore).

And since some people are wondering why this might be useful:

- A shell script `foo.sh` in the current directory cannot be called by `foo.sh` (except when `.` is in `$PATH`), but must instead be invoked using `./foo.sh`.
- As [*Boris* explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62687193/how-to-create-a-pathlib-relative-path-with-a-dot-starting-point#comment110955318_62687193), in a Node.js `require()` statement there’s a difference between `foo` and `./foo`.
- I myself needed this in order to create a file name argument to [ExifTool](https://www.exiftool.org/) that’s guaranteed to not be parsed as a command line option, even if the file is for example called `-quiet`. ExifTool doesn’t adhere to the Unix convention of having a `--` argument that denotes all the following argument to not be options, and the official [suggestion by its author](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=10244.msg53639#msg53639) is to “[p]ut the directory name before the file name if the file name begins with a dash”.